# looking for a regular expression to validate a password, must be greater than 8 characters long and contain at least one special character

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, passwords

looking to validate a password, currently i have

```
var myRegularExpression = /(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}/ ;
```

am i missing something? it can contain anything but the only requirements it must have are at least 1 special character and be greater than 8 characters

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Answer (score 0):

use this ^(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}$

you can see the details [here](https://regex101.com/r/MgmWth/2)

Comment: worked good but changed it to {9,} because a password greater than 8 characters means at least 9

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.

```js
/(.{7,}(?=[#?!@$%^&*-])|(?=[#?!@$%^&*-]).{7,})/
```

Answer (score 0):

This function can be used. Pass in a the password string to test it. If it is longer than 8 characters i will get tested by the RegEx test to see if there is a special character. If there is a special character it returns true if there is none them the "Password is either....." text is returned.

```
function passWrdTest(str){
    var myReg = /\[|\#|\?|\!|\@|\$|\%|\^|\&|\*|\-|\]/g;
    return str.length > 8 ? myReg.test(str) : 'Password is either not long enough or does not have a special character...';
}
```